# Customize CSS code based on selected woocommerce attribute

Tags: css, woocommerce

I added CSS code to create frames around woocommerce product images.

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image img { 
background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

It works with a simple product.

However, I don't know what to do with a variable product. Indeed, I want the frame to appear only when an attribute is selected.

For example, a variable product with 2 attributes:
-black
-white

I would like me to apply the following code for the white attribute

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image img { 
background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

And this one for the black attribute.

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image img { 
background-color: #000;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

I know that we can add images by variations but I want to work with CSS code, which is easier to manage.

Is there a specific class for the attribute? Should I use a php function?

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi Pierre, check out the attribute selector [w3schools: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Some CSS like `[-black] { ... }` and `[-white] { ... }` should work. Not sure about the dash, though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. I cannot select these attributes.